# Python for loops for repeated addition

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that creates a multiplication table of n x n.
It's required for the assignment to use repeated addition instead of the multiplication function.

This is the code I have so far:

```
def main():
import math
print('Hello!')
n = (abs(eval(input("Enter n for the multiplication table n x n: "))))
n = int(n)
a = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        a = i+a
        print(i,' * ',x,' = ',a)
main()
```

It gives me an output like this:

```
Hello!
Enter n for the multiplication table n x n: 4
1  *  1  =  1
1  *  2  =  2
1  *  3  =  3
1  *  4  =  4
2  *  1  =  6
2  *  2  =  8
2  *  3  =  10
2  *  4  =  12
3  *  1  =  15
3  *  2  =  18
3  *  3  =  21
3  *  4  =  24
4  *  1  =  28
4  *  2  =  32
4  *  3  =  36
4  *  4  =  40
```

The output is obviously incorrect, so what can I change/add to fix the calculations?

Comment: Please please please, do *not* use `eval(input(...))`. Use `int(input()` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variable `a` inside of your nested for loops that you continuously add values to for different values of the multiplication table. Instead of adding `i` to `a` each iteration, let `a = i*x`. This will give you the correct value of multiplication each time. However, if you really want to do it with repeated addition, set `a = 0` outside of the second for loop, but inside the first, like so:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        a = i+a
        print(i,' * ',x,' = ',a)
    a = 0
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `.format` in this case, it makes things cleaner: `print("{}*{} = {}".format(i, x, acc))`

Comment: That was what I was missing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For the print statement try using instead:

```
print(i,' * ',x,' = ',i*x)
```

I'm not certain what you are using the 'a' variable for, but if you'd like to output the multiplication of i and x still using a, instead keep your code the same and just change what you have for a in your nest for loop:

```
a = i*x
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked, but for the assignment, I can't use the multiplication function, i have to use repeated addition.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case I'd follow UnknowableIneffible's solution, as he addressed how to solve the problem with repeated addition.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you're always incrementing the variable 'a' by itself added to 'i' each time, instead you should multiply i*x

```
print("Hello!")

n = input("Enter n for the multiplication table n x n: ")
n = int(n)

result = 0

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        result = i*j
        print(i," * ", j, " = ", result)
```

Comment: Why do you have `result = 0`? It is no longer necessary.